# Django Emailfield fixed suffix

Tags: django, forms

In my Contact model I use an EmailField to assure I'm saving a valid email address.

In my form however, I only want the user to be able to change the part before the `@`, the domain part is not user defined. (e.g. every email needs to end with `@gmail.com`)

I have looked at a lot of questions about modifying Django form field values before and after validation and display phase, but a lot of the answers are kind of 'hacky' or seem to much of a workaround for my case.

Is there some support of kind of a display filter, which manages a fixed prefix/suffix of a Django form field, without having to edit POST values or needing to suppress certain validations?

Answer (score 0):

Use the clean method in your form to validate the email.  It'll be something like this

```
def clean(self):
    """Check if valid email for institution."""
    super().clean()
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data

    if not '@gmail.com' in cleaned_data['email']
        msg = forms.ValidationError("Your email must be @gmail")
        self.add_error('email', msg)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I do not want to throw a validationerror, but I want to silently add the domain part of the emailaddress before saving/validation and remove it before rendering

Comment: Then amend the cleaned_data within the clean method